# Exception ignored on Rails ActiveRecord save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying not to save a record in the database if an exception is raised but for some reason it is ignored. The record save anyway. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

# This is my controller

```
    # POST /users
      def create
        service_action(success: @support_user, fail: :new) do |service|
          service.create_user
        end
      end

    def service_action(page)
        result = yield(SupportUserService.new(@support_user, App.logger))
        if result[:ok]
          redirect_to page[:success], :notice => result[:message]
        else
          flash[:error] = result[:message] if result[:message].present?
          render page[:fail]
        end
      end
```

#This is in a service class -> SupportUserService

```
    def create_user
      return_hash(:create) do |h|
        if user.save
          grant_ssh_access(user.login, user_ssh_keys!)
          h[:ok] = true
          h[:message] = "Support User '#{user.login}' was successfully created."
        end
      end
    end


    def return_hash(action)
      {ok: false, message: ''}.tap do |h|
        begin
          yield h
        rescue => e
          h[:ok] = false
          h[:e] = e
          h[:message] = "Failed to #{action} support user: #{e.message}"
          logger.error(stacktrace("Failed to #{action} support user", e))
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Where is the exception being raised?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#save` with exception raise version `#save!`, and remove `if` clause, so you'll get:

```
return_hash(:create) do |h|
   user.save!
   grant_ssh_access(user.login, user_ssh_keys!)
   h[:ok] = true
   h[:message] = "Support User '#{user.login}' was successfully created."
end
```

This will throw an exception on save failure, and you will be able to trap it in the `#return_hash`.

Comment: Tried that but still having the same problem.

Comment: @user1576738 which problem exactly ? Where didn't you wish to get exception?

Comment: I'm getting the exception fine but the record still gets saved to the database anyway. I don't want that to happen.  So in other words if an exception is thrown it should show an error (which it does) but then exit and not save the record.

Comment: @user1576738 seems that record is saved not in the `user.save!` place, but in other one

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving the grant_ssh_access function outside of the user.save method. That way if that function returns an exception it gets trapped before reaching the save method and exits.